# Get word meaning from txt file using PHP

Tags: php

I have a txt file that contains a Persian-Esperanto dictionary like this:

آب: akvo

زیر آب بردن: subakvigi

I need a php code that get the word that I send it using POST request ( for example I send the word "آب" to it ) and show the meaning. also, If I send it an Esperanto word like "akvo", It show me the Persian word.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please note that SO is _not_ a free coding service. We are _not_ here to do your work for you. We are here to help with _specific issues_ you encounter _in your own code_. So start out yourself, code what you need and if you run into serious issues, _then_ is the time to come here, post your code and point out that issue you ran into.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filesystem.asp
Look there, what you are looking for is probably there.

Comment: I don't see the relation to the question at hand. Also, please note that so-called “link only answers” are not considered to be good answers.